# Ubuntu 18.04 Xorg.0.log is not in /var/log or anywhere else that I've looked - where is it?

Tags: xorg

Ubuntu 18.04, X version 1.19.6, graphics in use - AMD W600, all 6 outputs connected to 19x10 monitors. 
Desktop is configured with GDM3, Gnome Flashback (Metacity)
Driver in use - I think radeon or amdgpu, since they both show up in lsmod, but how do I know for sure without X log?

For some reason there is no Xorg.0.log file in /var/log

There is a /var/log/syslog file that contains some output that looks like it comes from X, but at the same time a lot of info that is normally found in xorg log, is not there. And that syslog is HUGE. 
Couldn't find anything on the web so far. 
Does anybody know where that X log is on Ubuntu 18.04?
Many thanks!

Update: Switched to xdm from gdm3 and lo and behold! The /var/log/Xorg.0.log is there! Still interesting - what's with gdm3 and X log?

Update: Thanks to Philippe Delteil - resolved. For some reason, when gdm3 is in use, the x log is not in /var/log, but in ~/.local/share/xorg.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to find the location of a file you can use the command locate, in the following way:

```
> sudo updatedb #updates the index of file names 

> locate Xorg.0.log
```

In my case the output is

> /home/username/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log

Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, that's interesting! I have it there too! Not with gdm3 though.

Comment: Actually, switched back to gdm3 and yes, the log is in the path, you've indicated, but not in /var/log/  Thanks!